# Import binary data using a different scanning direction

Tags: python, import, binary-data, direction

I have a C code that computes some physical variable on a 2D space (e.g. x-velocity "u" and y-velocity "v", where "u" and "v" are functions of spacial coordinates "x" and "y" : "u=u(x,y)" and "v=v(x,y)").

It then exports the results in a binary file (data type is "double"). I then open the data file with a python script so that I can make some post-processing and plot the data using matplotlib.

As you know there are two ways to scan a 2D array :

- either you first select a line and scan each cell inside the line
- or you do exactly the opposite : first select a column and scan each cell in the column

Obviously, I face an issue where the direction in which the array is saved by my C code is different from the direction the array is read by my python script.

The C file uses the `fwrite()` function, and I want to keep it as it is.

```
fwrite(vect , sizeof(double), nbcols*nbrows, file);
```

The python file uses the struct module to unpack the array :

```
unpackFormat = '%dd' % nDim
zx = np.array([struct.unpack(unpackFormat,f.read())]).reshape(v.N,v.M)
```

In my particular case, I can find a workaround but it is ugly and might not work in all situations. So here's my question : is there any way to unpack the array so that it is scanned in the other direction than the default one ?

My array only contains doubles, and if I understand properly, `array.fromfile` can handle that kind of situations, so if you happen to know the answer for `array.fromfile`, feel free to share it !

---

### Extra information on my particular case

In the following, I include more details that are specific to my problem, though what I have just expressed should be enough for you to understand my problem. Note : there is going to be some numpy+matplolib in the following, even though my problem is related to the struct module more than it is related to matplotlib.

What I want is to do is a quiver plot of a velocity field. This means I want to plot a "field of arrows" as in [here][1] where an arrow on point (x,y) corresponds to the vector (u(x,y),v(x,y)). Here is the interesting part of my script :

```
# gen x,y coordinates
y, x = np.mgrid[0:1:complex(0,v.N),
                0:1:complex(0,v.M)]

# load data for the x-direction
f = open(filePathX, 'rb')
unpackFormat = '%dd' % nDim
zx = np.array([struct.unpack(unpackFormat,f.read())]).reshape(v.N,v.M)
f.close()

# load data for the y-direction
f = open(filePathY, 'rb')
unpackFormat = '%dd' % nDim
zy = np.array([struct.unpack(unpackFormat,f.read())]).reshape(v.N,v.M)
f.close()

# plotting
plt.quiver(x[::10,::10], y[::10,::10], zx[::10,::10], zy[::10,::10])
```

With this script, the plot is not well plotted : it is as if the x and y coordinates of the output vectors zx and zy had been swapped. In other words, each arrow corresponds to vector (v,u) instead of vector (u,v). I attribute this to `struct.unpack` reading the array in the other direction that the one I would have hoped for.

In my particular case, I was hopping for a rotating velocity field, but instead the arrows point either inwards or outwards on the X and Y axes.

Important precision : Matplotlib does no allow me to swap x and y arrays.

A work around is to do the following :

```
plt.quiver(x[::10,::10], y[::10,::10], -zy[::10,::10], -zx[::10,::10])
```

But I do not like this way of doing things, so I am hoping for you to suggest a better way to fix my issue

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me just found the answer :

use :

```
zx = np.array([struct.unpack(unpackFormat,f.read())]).reshape(v.N,v.M,order='F')
```

instead of :

```
zx = np.array([struct.unpack(unpackFormat,f.read())]).reshape(v.N,v.M)
```

Doing so changes the way the array is read. Actually the problem did not come from `struct.unpack` but from `np.array.reshape`. The latter has an optional argument to set the scanning direction. Here I chose the `F` option for "fortran" scanning convention (even though my data was saved by a C code) instead of the default `C` value (for C scanning convention).

I suppose I must have stored the arrays in an odd fashion from the start in my C code and therefore I need to read them in an unconventional way. Still bothers me, but at least it the script looks clean.